# Count annotation with prefetch_related

Tags: python, django, orm, django-select-related

**Edit:** Both of the following snippets actually run fine with no errors! It was a typo elsewhere in my codebase.

Is there a way to write an ORM call such that I can get a count annotation of ManyToMany objects and prefetch_related those objects?

e.g.

```
movies = Movies.objects.filter()
movies = movies.annotate(genre_count=Count('genre'))
movies = movies.prefetch_related('genre_set')

for movie in movies:
    genres = movie.genre_set.all()
    genre_count = movie.genre_count
```

This throws AttributeError: 'Movie' object has no attribute 'genre_count', whereas

```
movies = Movies.objects.filter()
movies = movies.annotate(genre_count=Count('genre'))

for movie in movies:
    genre_count = movie.genre_count
```

works fine

Comment: Could you please show your models?

Comment: Nevermind, the above code should work fine. I had simplified the example from juggling around a QuerySet in my codebase. Turns out it was an unrelated typo.